# What would be a good datamodel to describe a datamodel?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm considering a "simple" project, where I can create a datamodel based on an existing database and store this datamodel inside another database. Consider it a meta-datamodel. Basically, I would have a "Database" table, listing the databases and linked to this the "Table" table listing the tables per database. Then a "Fields" table listing all fields per table. And then I need to fit in the keys, constraints and other stuff...
Before starting to re-invent the wheel, has anyone else done this before, already? 
(*And I'm only interested in a meta-datamodel, not some tool to manage them!*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the ISO Information Schema catalogue. This is the standard method of describing the schema as supported by SQL Server, Oracle and other DBMSs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Comment: Looks promising! :-) But it might be a bit too complex. The keyword "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" I found is very useful, though!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the canonical definition of a RDBMS mandated that all the metadata was stored within the database itself. So, by definition, a RDBMS ought to already have this and SQL server provides a whole slew of System views to allow you to query all this, so you could use those as a basis for your meta-model.